# Как составить правило в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Помогите пожалуйста настроить 301 редирект.

Редирект с

```
/shop/product/telefon
/shop/product/televizor
/shop/product/monitor
```

на

```
/telefon.html
/televizor.html
/monitor.html
```

---

С

```
/shop/category/televizory
/shop/category/futbolki
```

На

```
/televizory.html
/futbolki.html
```

`telefon` \ `televizor` \ `monitor` - любое значение

Просто делаю переезд на новую CMS, и требуется переадресация на новое ЧПУ.

Comment: Вы уже попробовали что-то сделать самостоятельно?

Comment: С таким подходом можно везде такое писать.

Comment: У нас тут [600 отвеченных вопросов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D+answers%3A1+is%3Aquestion) по метке [tag:.htaccess]. Точно нет подходящего решения?

Comment: @Lev в большинстве задаваемых здесь вопросов автор действительно пытается самостоятельно решить задачу.

Answer (score 0):

Проверить можно с помощью [htaccess Tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop/(product|category)/(.+) /$1.html
```